# multiplie image upload url and file name is not working

Tags: javascript

my problem is when I select the multiple images it displaying correct, and I am storing this in one array, from that array I need to get the image name. right now it's working but in `setOfImages` array all image name is same. i need to take the image URL also when i put that `setOfImages` array in map function that URL are get repeating this are two problems I am facing if not clear put `console.log(setOfImages)` and `console.log(imageUrl)`,

```
imagetrigger(e){
var setOfImages =[], imageUrl=[];
for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++){ 
    var file = e.target.files[i];
    if(!file.type.match('image'))
    continue;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        setOfImages.push({
             fileName:file.name,
             image:e.target.result.split(',')[1]
        });
        $('.image').remove();
        for(var j = 0; j<setOfImages.length; j++) {
            $('.placeholder').prepend('<div class="image"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ setOfImages[j].image +'" /></div>');
        }
        setOfImages.map(function(){
            imageUrl.push(el.fileName);
        })
        console.log(imageUrl)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add parameter `el` to your map.

```
setOfImages.map(function(){
  imageUrl.push(el.fileName);
})
```

Change like this.

```
setOfImages.map(function(el){
  imageUrl.push(el.fileName);
})
```